# CocoaPodsでFirebaseを複数ターゲットにインストールするとクラッシュする

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

現在、Embedded Framework で複数ターゲットに分割して開発しているのですが、
CocoaPodsでFirebaseを複数ターゲットにインストールすると起動後にクラッシュしてしまいます。

```
objc[97307]: Class FIRMessagingLog is implemented in both /Users/yuto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bgkajtjdcnvxnxexzeaimkikirwu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.framework/App (0x10393ad98) and /Users/yuto/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/871E1A28-1266-4B31-BF14-A84577AA550D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/81283C37-9D64-425F-A316-9303BD252618/App.app/App (0x1020f43b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97307]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x12556c4d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x1246bae38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2018-06-28 10:58:37.719414+0900 App[97307:3379853] 5.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
```

Podfileは以下のようにしています。

```
abstract_target 'Top' do
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '10.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  target 'App' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for App

    target 'AppTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end

  end

  target 'AppExtension' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for AppExtension

  end

  target 'AppFlux' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for AppFlux

  end

  target 'AppKit' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for AppKit

  end

  target 'AppUI' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for AppUI

  end
end
```

環境
Xcode: 9.4.1
CocoaPods: 5.0.1

下記を参考にしましたが、具体的な解決策が見つからず困っています
- https://teratail.com/questions/87567
- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/231

ご回答いただけるととても嬉しく思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseはFrameworkの体裁を取っていますが、実際はStatic Libraryです。複数のフレームワークにリンクすると、複数のシンボルがリンクされてしまいます。
また、CocoaPodsの現在の使用により、１つのターゲットにリンクしたとしても、すべてのターゲットにリンカフラグが設定されるので、結局は同じ問題が起こります。
解決方法はいろいろありますが、基本的には１つのターゲットにリンクするようにして、他のターゲットからはそのフレームワークをImportする形で使用することです。
で、具体的にCocoaPodsでどうしたらいいかというと、
どれか１つのターゲットだけにリンクするようにPodfileを構成し、その上でさらに、

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftGen'
pod 'SwiftLint'
pod 'LicensePlist'

target 'XXXApp' do
  pod 'Shimmer', inhibit_warnings: true

  target 'XXXAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Mockingjay', inhibit_warnings: true
    pod 'iOSSnapshotTestCase', inhibit_warnings: true
  end

  target 'XXXAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'Foo' do
  pod 'GoogleTagManager', inhibit_warnings: true

  target 'FooTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Mockingjay', inhibit_warnings: true
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
        puts aggregate_target.name
        if aggregate_target.name == 'Pods-XXXApp'
            aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
                config_file.libraries.delete('GoogleAnalytics')

                config_file.frameworks.delete('FirebaseAnalytics')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('FirebaseCore')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('FirebaseCoreDiagnostics')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('FirebaseInstanceID')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('FirebaseNanoPB')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('GoogleSymbolUtilities')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('GoogleTagManager')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('GoogleToolboxForMac')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('GoogleUtilities')
                config_file.frameworks.delete('nanopb')

                xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
                config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

^ 上記のように、リンクしないターゲットからはFirebaseに関連するライブラリのリンカフラグを取り除く、というのが最も分かりやすい解決法だと思います。
この例だと、XXXAppとFooというターゲットがあって、FooはEmbeddedFrameworkです。FirebaseはFooにのみリンクしています。
（GoogleTagManagerがFirebaseAnalyticsに依存しています。）
しかし、CocoaPodsがXXXAppにもリンカフラグを設定してしまうので、XXXAppからFirebase関連のライブラリのリンカフラグを取り除いています。
ターゲットが増えても理屈は同じです。